# Malicious Code or False Positive?

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

I ran "Sucuri SiteCheck" in one site that im working and the sitecheck reported the following code as malware:

Known javascript malware.

Details:

> http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/mwjs-include-unescape3?v1

code:

```
var i,y,x="3c646976207374796c653d22706f736974696f6e3a6162736f6c7574653b6c6566743a3070783b746f703a3070783b7669736962696c6974793a68696464656e3b222069643d2264617461646976223e3c696d67207372633d2267706c75732e637322206865696768743d2230222077696474683d2230223e3c2f696d673e3c2f6469763e";y='';for(i=0;i<x.length;i+=2){y+=unescape('%'+x.substr(i,2));}document.write(y);</script></aside><aside id="bp-4" class="WP"><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">//
```

After search I found this code in one file

```
"<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">//\nvar i,y,x=\"$hex_string\";y='';for(i=0;i<x.length;i+=2){y+=unescape('%'+x.substr(i,2));}document.write(y);</script>"
```

Someone can tell me what this code do, and it is really malicious ?

Thank you very much!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Sucuri SiteCheck doesn't like the way it was obfuscated. Decoding it as hex, it is:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;visibility:hidden;" id="datadiv">
    <img src="gplus.cs" height="0" width="0">
    </img>
</div>
```

The question as to whether or not it is malicious depends on what `gplus.cs` is.

Comment: Thank you David, now i question myself why this are obfuscated. I can use the decoded code to help with the sitecheck alarm?

Comment: @kodden I haven't used sitecheck, but I suppose you could provide it with the URL of gplus.cs to let it scan that.

Comment: gplus.cs doesnt sound like an image - it is looking for something local to the script - are you certain nothing has been slipped ont your server near the page the script was on? "datadiv" sounds suspicious doesn't it!

Comment: It may just end up being a tracking pixel. Or it might be a browser exploit designed to execute arbitrary code when the file is attempted to be viewed as an image. Hard to say.

Comment: Googled gplus.cs and came up with what looks like a games company  gplus.csgames.org - goes to https://plus.google.com/s/gplus.cs/top on search which has adverts...may not be visciously malicious but makes you wonder about oogleG  Also more oogly stuff comes up with lots of .cs  https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDsO_6sqPJAhUC1hoKHZmxBlw4ChAWCBwwAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogleplus%2Fgplus-verifytoken-csharp%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fverifytoken.ashx.cs&usg=AFQjCNHRsTyP_edO11C8xOgdRECId7M3lA&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d2s